# Insert data into table with result from another select query for one column

Tags: mysql

```
INSERT INTO master_table (`Group_No`, `Group_Name`,`Order_No`) VALUES (6,'Purchase Account','SELECT Order_no FROM acc_group_master where Group_No=1')
```

How can i insert data into Order_No column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  can try this

```
INSERT INTO master_table (`Group_No`, `Group_Name`,`Order_No`)
SELECT 6,'Purchase Account',Order_no FROM acc_group_master where Group_No=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have surrounded your subquery with quotes `'..'` wich make it becomes a string and been inserted as it is in your database, simply remove quotes and apply brackets instead

```
INSERT INTO master_table (`Group_No`, `Group_Name`,`Order_No`) 
VALUES (6,'Purchase Account',(SELECT Order_no FROM acc_group_master where Group_No=1))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO master_table (`Group_No`, `Group_Name`,`Order_No`) VALUES
(SELECT 6, 'purchase Account', Order_no FROM acc_group_master where Group_No=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
INSERT INTO master_table (`Group_No`, `Group_Name`,`Order_No`) VALUES 
(6,'Purchase Account',(SELECT Order_no FROM acc_group_master where Group_No=1))
```